"SHOW DATABASE" Returns `Resources Exhausted` Error in CnosDB After Long Uptime
I encountered an issue with a single-node CnosDB deployment:

Deployment Details:

CnosDB Version: 2.3.5 (revision ace7d5f)
Deployment Type: Singleton


Reproduction Steps:

Started a single-node CnosDB service.
Used the TSBS tool to write data:

/bin/cat /data/data/line_protocol/cnosdb_iot_123_100_6.3_2020-2025_5y_data.gz | /bin/gunzip | /bin/load_cnosdb --batch-size 1 --workers 1 --urls "http://192.168.0.23:12002"  


After running the service for 6 weeks, I attempted a query using SHOW DATABASE.


Issue:
The query fails and returns the following error:


{"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Resources exhausted: Failed to allocate additional 5304 bytes with 0 bytes already allocated - maximum available is 168"}  


Observations:

The write status output:

1733280336,0.00,8.436378E+08,1086.06,0.00,1.066552E+08,137.30  
1733280346,0.00,8.436378E+08,1086.04,0.00,1.066552E+08,137.30  
1733280356,0.00,8.436378E+08,1086.03,0.00,1.066552E+08,137.30  


System monitoring indicates that the system resources (CPU, memory, etc.) are sufficient.



Does anyone know what could be causing this resource exhaustion error? Any suggestions for debugging or resolving this issue are appreciated.
